# Conflict with Google maps V3 API and MooTools

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mootools

I'm have a conflict with Google Maps v3 API and Mootools. For some reason when the page where the maps is on is loaded it looks fine but about 10 seconds later the map disappears as well as all but 1 pin point.

You can see it here:  http://goo.gl/Sr0b2

If I remove mootools.js which loads in my footer, the problem goes away but then some of the javascript on my WordPress theme doesn't work such as the drop down menu in the header so removing mootools is not an option.

Anyone know what may be causing the conflict and how I can fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possibly window related objects, setTimeouts, prototype overrides etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using an iframe for the map, this way the mootools.js on the page doesn't affect the map script.  I usually don't use iframes but in this situation it doesn't affect the site's SEO or anything else and it's a perfect solution. So if you have this same issue you can load the map on a page of its own (with nothing but the map) and then insert it anywhere with